# undefined local variable or method `subjects_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to search text from mysql db table .

view page:

```
<% form_tag subjects_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**controller code:**

```
  before_action :confirm_logged_in

  def index
    @subjects=Subject.sorted   
     @subjects = Subject.search params[:search]
  end'
```

**Routes used:**

```
 root 'demo#index'

  get 'admin', :to=> "access#index"

  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))' ,:via=>[:get,:post]
```

i am waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

in routes.rb you need to define the subjects

`resources :subjects, only: [:index]`

You've not specified any named routes so `subjects_path` doesn't exist.

Comment: And if you'd like to add other routes to subjects (i.e. for editing etc.) just add `resources :subjects`.